# How to ensure an application will be compliant with 64 bit?

Tags: android, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, cpu-architecture

Important links:

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html

https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit#assess_your_app

As you can read there:

> Starting August 1, 2019: All new apps and app updates that include
>   native code are required to provide 64-bit versions in addition to
>   32-bit versions when publishing to Google Play.

When you read that, you can understand that you **must** upload two versions of your app, one compiled for 32 bits and one compiled for 64 bits.

But then you can read this:

> Look for native libraries using APK Analyzer APK Analyzer is a tool
>   that allows you to evaluate various aspects of a built APK. In our
>   case, we're going to use it to find any native libraries, and ensure
>   64-bit libraries are present.
>
> 1. Open Android Studio, and open any project.
> 2. From the menu, select Build > Analyze APK…
> 3. launch APK analyzer
> 4. Choose the APK you wish to evaluate.
> 5. Look within the lib folder, which is where you will find any '.so' files. If you can not find any '.so' files in your app at all, then
>      your app is already ready and no further action is required. If you
>      see armeabi-v7a or x86, then you have 32-bit libraries.

Important point:

**Look within the lib folder, which is where you will find any '.so' files. If you can not find any '.so' files in your app at all, then your app is already ready and no further action is required**

In my case I'm developing with Java code, and I can't find a `lib` folder using APK Analyzer, so... in theory, no further action is required. But then, why they say that *"Starting August 1, 2019 All new apps and app updates that include native code are required to provide 64-bit versions in addition to 32-bit versions when publishing to Google Play."* ?

Would be necessary for me to do something? Or can I continue uploading my single APK like until now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To clarify, the 64-bit requirement is only for projects which besides Java also use native binaries, and by native binaries it means c/c++ compiled .so files. 
The requirement specifies that besides 32-bit binaries, the developer must include also the 64-bit variants. This can be done in 2 ways, as usual with a single APK containing both binary types (32-bit & 64-bit .so files), or splitting it into 2 APK flavors.

Either way, **if you have developed your project using only Java then you don’t need to worry**, unless you have dependencies on third-party libraries which use native binaries on their own. In such scenario you must ensure that any of your project dependencies also include the 64-bit native variants.

In your case, if you can't find any ***.so** file in your APK then there is no further action you need to take, everything is good to go.

Comment: How to open APK in Mac? Where can I see files? Where is .so file?

Comment: To see the contents of any APK, in Android Studio, you can use the "Analyze APK" tool located in the "Build" menu. In addition, an APK is in fact a zip file, so, you can also rename its extension from apk to zip, and then you will be able to browse and extract its contents. Native libraries are found in the "lib" sub-folders.